# Build Tensorflow 2.7 from source error in Jetson nano using python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, bazel, nvidia-jetson-nano

I want to compile Tensorflow 2.7 with Python 3.7 in NVIDIA Jetson Nano, but after several hours the process faileed with following error.

```bash
ERROR: /home/acd/tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/BUILD:572:11: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow:tensorflow_ops' failed (Exit 4): crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/acd/.cache/bazel/_bazel_acd/cde8dcf7cee5950e7dfb9a438207f0dd/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.2 \
    GCC_HOST_COMPILER_PATH=/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-7 \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64: \
    PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin:/home/acd/.local/bin:/home/acd/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python3.7 \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages \
    TF2_BEHAVIOR=1 \
    TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=5.3 \
  external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -MD -MF bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/_objs/tensorflow_ops/tf_ops.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/_objs/tensorflow_ops/tf_ops.pic.o' '-DLLVM_ON_UNIX=1' '-DHAVE_BACKTRACE=1' '-DBACKTRACE_HEADER=<execinfo.h>' '-DLTDL_SHLIB_EXT=".so"' '-DLLVM_PLUGIN_EXT=".so"' '-DLLVM_ENABLE_THREADS=1' '-DHAVE_SYSEXITS_H=1' '-DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1' '-DHAVE_STRERROR_R=1' '-DHAVE_LIBPTHREAD=1' '-DHAVE_PTHREAD_GETNAME_NP=1' '-DHAVE_PTHREAD_SETNAME_NP=1' '-DHAVE_PTHREAD_GETSPECIFIC=1' '-DHAVE_REGISTER_FRAME=1' '-DHAVE_DEREGISTER_FRAME=1' -D_GNU_SOURCE '-DHAVE_LINK_H=1' '-DHAVE_LSEEK64=1' '-DHAVE_MALLINFO=1' '-DHAVE_POSIX_FALLOCATE=1' '-DHAVE_SBRK=1' '-DHAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIM_TV_NSEC=1' '-DLLVM_NATIVE_ARCH="AArch64"' '-DLLVM_NATIVE_ASMPARSER=LLVMInitializeAArch64AsmParser' '-DLLVM_NATIVE_ASMPRINTER=LLVMInitializeAArch64AsmPrinter' '-DLLVM_NATIVE_DISASSEMBLER=LLVMInitializeAArch64Disassembler' '-DLLVM_NATIVE_TARGET=LLVMInitializeAArch64Target' '-DLLVM_NATIVE_TARGETINFO=LLVMInitializeAArch64TargetInfo' '-DLLVM_NATIVE_TARGETMC=LLVMInitializeAArch64TargetMC' '-DLLVM_NATIVE_TARGETMCA=LLVMInitializeAArch64TargetMCA' '-DLLVM_HOST_TRIPLE="aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu"' '-DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE="aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu"' -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY '-DEIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=64' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin -iquote external/llvm-project -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project -iquote external/llvm_terminfo -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm_terminfo -iquote external/llvm_zlib -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm_zlib -iquote external/com_google_absl -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/com_google_absl -iquote external/nsync -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/nsync -iquote external/eigen_archive -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -iquote external/gif -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/gif -iquote external/libjpeg_turbo -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/libjpeg_turbo -iquote external/com_google_protobuf -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf -iquote external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote external/farmhash_archive -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive -iquote external/fft2d -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/fft2d -iquote external/highwayhash -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/highwayhash -iquote external/zlib -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/zlib -iquote external/local_config_cuda -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/local_config_cuda -iquote external/double_conversion -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/double_conversion -iquote external/local_config_rocm -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/local_config_rocm -iquote external/local_config_tensorrt -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/local_config_tensorrt -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/BuiltinAttributeInterfacesIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/BuiltinAttributesIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/BuiltinDialectIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/BuiltinLocationAttributesIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/BuiltinOpsIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/BuiltinTypeInterfacesIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/BuiltinTypesIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/CallOpInterfacesIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/CastOpInterfacesIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/InferTypeOpInterfaceIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/OpAsmInterfaceIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/RegionKindInterfaceIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/SideEffectInterfacesIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/SubElementInterfacesIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/SymbolInterfacesIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/TensorEncodingIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/ParserTokenKinds -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/local_config_cuda/cuda/_virtual_includes/cuda_headers_virtual -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/local_config_tensorrt/_virtual_includes/tensorrt_headers -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/ControlFlowInterfacesIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/DerivedAttributeOpInterfaceIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/LoopLikeInterfaceIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/StandardOpsIncGen -Ibazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/_virtual_includes/VectorInterfacesIncGen -isystem external/llvm-project/llvm/include -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/llvm/include -isystem external/llvm-project/mlir/include -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/llvm-project/mlir/include -isystem external/nsync/public -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/nsync/public -isystem external/eigen_archive -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -isystem external/gif -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/gif -isystem external/com_google_protobuf/src -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src -isystem external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem external/zlib -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/zlib -isystem external/local_config_cuda/cuda -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/local_config_cuda/cuda -isystem external/local_config_cuda/cuda/cuda/include -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/local_config_cuda/cuda/cuda/include -isystem external/double_conversion -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/double_conversion -isystem external/local_config_rocm/rocm -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/local_config_rocm/rocm -isystem external/local_config_rocm/rocm/rocm/include -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/local_config_rocm/rocm/rocm/include -isystem external/local_config_rocm/rocm/rocm/include/rocrand -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/local_config_rocm/rocm/rocm/include/rocrand -isystem external/local_config_rocm/rocm/rocm/include/roctracer -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/external/local_config_rocm/rocm/rocm/include/roctracer -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -fPIC -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -Wall -fno-omit-frame-pointer -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-canonical-system-headers -DNDEBUG -g0 -O2 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -DAUTOLOAD_DYNAMIC_KERNELS '-std=c++14' -c tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/ir/tf_ops.cc -o bazel-out/aarch64-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/_objs/tensorflow_ops/tf_ops.pic.o)
Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-7: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 53520.933s, Critical Path: 27882.90s
INFO: 5993 processes: 944 internal, 5049 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Here's my configuration

```bash
acd@acd-jetson:~/tensorflow$ ./configure
You have bazel 3.7.2- (@non-git) installed.
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python3]: /usr/bin/python3.7


Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages]

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with ROCm support? [y/N]: n
No ROCm support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]: y
CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with TensorRT support? [y/N]: y
TensorRT support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Found CUDA 10.2 in:
    /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/aarch64-linux/lib
    /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/aarch64-linux/include
Found cuDNN 8 in:
    /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    /usr/include
Found TensorRT 8 in:
    /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu


Please specify a list of comma-separated CUDA compute capabilities you want to build with.
You can find the compute capability of your device at: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus. Each capability can be specified as "x.y" or "compute_xy" to include both virtual and binary GPU code, or as "sm_xy" to only include the binary code.
Please note that each additional compute capability significantly increases your build time and binary size, and that TensorFlow only supports compute capabilities >= 3.5 [Default is: 3.5,7.0]: 5.3


Do you want to use clang as CUDA compiler? [y/N]: n
nvcc will be used as CUDA compiler.

Please specify which gcc should be used by nvcc as the host compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/gcc]:


Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -Wno-sign-compare]:


Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android builds? [y/N]: n
Not configuring the WORKSPACE for Android builds.

Preconfigured Bazel build configs. You can use any of the below by adding "--config=<>" to your build command. See .bazelrc for more details.
        --config=mkl            # Build with MKL support.
        --config=mkl_aarch64    # Build with oneDNN and Compute Library for the Arm Architecture (ACL).
        --config=monolithic     # Config for mostly static monolithic build.
        --config=numa           # Build with NUMA support.
        --config=dynamic_kernels        # (Experimental) Build kernels into separate shared objects.
        --config=v1             # Build with TensorFlow 1 API instead of TF 2 API.
Preconfigured Bazel build configs to DISABLE default on features:
        --config=nogcp          # Disable GCP support.
        --config=nonccl         # Disable NVIDIA NCCL support.
Configuration finished
```

Cause Jetson Nano use TensorRT 8.2 which isn't supported in tensorflow 2.7 by default, I use following command based on this guide [Tensorflow v2.7.0 = TensorRT8.2 build](https://zenn.dev/pinto0309/scraps/992c2a1e4d6e2f).

```bash
cp tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/stub/NvInfer_8_0.inc tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/stub/NvInfer_8_2.inc
sed -i '62a #elif NV_TENSORRT_MAJOR == 8 && NV_TENSORRT_MINOR == 2' tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/stub/nvinfer_stub.cc
sed -i '63a #include "tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/stub/NvInfer_8_2.inc"' tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/stub/nvinfer_stub.cc

cp tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/stub/NvInferPlugin_8_0.inc tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/stub/NvInferPlugin_8_2.inc
sed -i '62a #elif NV_TENSORRT_MAJOR == 8 && NV_TENSORRT_MINOR == 2' tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/stub/nvinfer_plugin_stub.cc
sed -i '63a #include "tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/stub/NvInferPlugin_8_2.inc"' tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/stub/nvinfer_plugin_stub.cc
```

And here's my build command

```bash
bazel build --config=cuda --config=nonccl --verbose_failures //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You have a bug in the compiler. Use a newest version (and hope the bug are corrected). Else (but I think you are using a very old version): report the bug, and so you will have a hint on how to correct the problem

Comment: Follow the standard configuration from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) seems mismatch with the version. Reference https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44692

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, I've using GCC 8.4 but it gives similar error
`C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/compiler/mlir/hlo:hlo' failed (Exit 1): crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed - Google Search`

Comment: NVIDIA provides the tensorflow 2.7 wheel for Python 3.6 means they manage to build it somehow, so I think there's a way to overcome the mismatched version.
@SG_Bazel